# Should URLs in meta tags contain ampersands?

Tags: html, facebook, encoding, facebook-opengraph, urlencode

Should a URL inside a meta tag contain ampersands directly or `&amp;`?  For example, this meta tag for working with Facebook's Open Graph:

```
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://somesite.com/api?url=http%3A%2F%2Fnews.website.com/img/4000%2Fjpg%2F_68009935_0198987080.jpg&amp;width=400&amp;height=400&amp;key=1234" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meta tag for image is url which facebook accesses to get the image. No need to put `&amp` just use `&` directly.